# Why this SOAP-ENV:Server message occurs on the second test case?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soa, bpel

I am developing this BPEL module which is interacting with a service on the localhost.

When I run the first test case, I receive the correct output. However, when I create a second test case, it fails and outputs this error message:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure; Fault Data is &amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:message xmlns:sxeh=&amp;quot;http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;sxeh:faultMessage&amp;quot; version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; xmlns:jbi=&amp;quot;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jbi/wsdl-11-wrapper&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:part&amp;gt;BPCOR-6174: Selection Failure occurred in BPEL({http://enterprise.netbeans.org/bpel/BpelModuleHope2/fucking_bpel}fucking_bpel) at line 49&amp;lt;/jbi:part&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/jbi:message&amp;gt;. Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance</faultstring>
      <faultactor>sun-bpel-engine</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <detailText>BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure; Fault Data is &amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:message xmlns:sxeh=&amp;quot;http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;sxeh:faultMessage&amp;quot; version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; xmlns:jbi=&amp;quot;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jbi/wsdl-11-wrapper&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;jbi:part&amp;gt;BPCOR-6174: Selection Failure occurred in BPEL({http://enterprise.netbeans.org/bpel/BpelModuleHope2/fucking_bpel}fucking_bpel) at line 49&amp;lt;/jbi:part&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/jbi:message&amp;gt;. Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance
   Caused by: BPCOR-6174: Selection Failure occurred in BPEL({http://enterprise.netbeans.org/bpel/BpelModuleHope2/fucking_bpel}fucking_bpel) at line 49
BPCOR-6129: Line Number is 47
BPCOR-6130: Activity Name is Assign2</detailText>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

However, if I restart the tomcat server and re-run a test, it works fine. But the second test case fails.

Do you think, it is a problem with the java implementation for the service?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To your last question, yes, it is probably something in the java implementation -- There is no possible way for us to help you unless you provide us your request, and some example code that might give us an opportunity to reproduce or discern the issue.